# Locating the column where dataframe-column-title first letter changes

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, split

I have a pandas DataFrame which columns' name are something the like: BT_XXX_XX.XX%_X.XX.XX ; EH_XXX_XX.XX%_XX.XX.XX ; C_XXX_XX.XX%_XX.XX.XX where X represents any alphanumerical character. They are completely disorganized.

I want to split the DataFrame in different DataFrames containing BT_*,EH_* and C_* (as I would similarly do in bash scripting).

I have sorted them in alphabetic order to bring the BT_*, EH_* and C_* in order. However, I do not know how to automatize to look for that first string to create a whole new DataFrame.

For the moment I can do this manually by checking every time the position of each set of columns.

```
#Sorting the dataframe by alphabetical order
dataset = dataset.reindex(sorted(dataset.columns), axis=1)

#Splitting the dataframe
df1 = dataset.iloc[:, :72]
df2 = dataset.iloc[:, 72:148]
df3 = dataset.iloc[148, 148:]
```

I would like to have this action automatized to avoid checking where BT_* columns finish and where EH_* or C_* start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use filter columns using str's startswith function like in example below no need to sort the columns before this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10), columns=[f"{a}_{i}" for i in range(5) for a in "AB"])

df1= df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith("A_")]
df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith("B_")]

display(df1.head())
display(df2.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` to split the DataFrame on the stub before the first `'_'`. You can store them in a dict with the stubs as the keys.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['BT_XXX_XX.XX%_X.XX.XX', 'BT_13131_1231231', 
                           'EH_XXX_XX.XX%_XX.XX.XX', 'C_XXX_XX.XX%_XX.XX.XX'])

dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1)))
```

---

```
{'BT': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [BT_XXX_XX.XX%_X.XX.XX, BT_13131_1231231]
 Index: [], 
'C': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [C_XXX_XX.XX%_XX.XX.XX]
 Index: [], 
'EH': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [EH_XXX_XX.XX%_XX.XX.XX]
 Index: []}
```